# put condition in first array on has many laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I had some issues filtering data with my eloquent query builder. I have Transaction Model and Status Model. which transaction has many status. I want to get the first array of hasMany relation and put where. Here is my code.

```
$var = Transaction::with([
          'status' => function ($q) {
              return $q->first();
           }
       ])->whereHas('status',function ($x){
           return $x->where('status',0);
       })->get();
```

and the model of a status is

```
public function status(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Status','transaction_id','id')->orderBy('status','desc');
}
```

the result still not give me the right data. it should by returning the data where the first array status value is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build a new relation using hasOne relation, then load it:

```
public function firstStatus(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Status','transaction_id','id')->orderBy('status','desc')->where('status',0);  // or mybe just ' ->latest() to get the most recent one.
}
```

then, you can use this relation like:

```
$var = Transaction::with(['firstStatus'])->whereHas('status',function ($x){
           return $x->where('status',0);
       })->get();
```

this the loaded relation will be the first one.

Comment: ->whereHas('status') means the model or the function that return has many ?

Comment: yes, this whereHas will ensure that you have that status, here, you can use either relation

Answer (score 0):

You can create another function for that or change exist function

```
public function firstStatus() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Status','transaction_id','id')->orderBy('status','desc')->limit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because of [OMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10573560/omr) finally i can figure it out

first i have to set model like [OMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10573560/omr) said like :

```
public function firstStatus(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Status','transaction_id','id')->orderBy('status','desc');  // or mybe just ' ->latest() to get the most recent one.
```

}

and put the controller like :

```
$var = Transaction::with(['firstStatus' => function($q){
        return $q->where('status',0);
   }])->whereHas('status',function ($x){
       return $x->where('status',0);
   })->get();
```

thanks [OMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10573560/omr)